# For relations :  → , :  →  such that  =  ⊆ , prove that ( ∘ )−1 = ^(−1) ∘ ^(−1)

Tags: real-analysis, relations

Q:For relations :  → , :  →  such that  =  ⊆ , prove that
( ∘ )−1 = ^(−1) ∘ ^(−1)

How to do the proof?
Is it ok to show both are subsets of each other and then say they are equal?
i.e showing ( ∘ )^−1 ⊆ [^(−1) ∘ ^(−1)] and [^(−1) ∘ ^(−1)] ⊆ ( ∘ )^−1 & then say
( ∘ )−1 = ^(−1) ∘ ^(−1)
Is there a other way??

Comment: Use mathjax please

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)